# Removing milliseconds from datetime object in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to remove the milliseconds(28109) from this string `2017-09-12 22:33:55.28109` in Python.

code:

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date,datetime

created_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(ctime)
d=datetime.strptime(created_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ")
created_date = datetime.strftime(d, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
print(created_date)
```

Error:

```
`d=datetime.strptime(created_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ")`
```

`TypeError: must be str, not datetime.datetime`

Comment: `created_date` is already a datetime, why are you passing it to `datetime.strptime`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *already have a `datetime` object*, you do not need to parse it again. The `datetime.fromtimestamp()` call was enough.

Remove the `datetime.strptime()` line.

```
created_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(ctime)
created_date = created_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
print(created_date)
```

I also changed your `strftime()` call, it is a method, you just call it on the `datetime` object you have.

I suspect that you printed the return value of the `datetime.fromtimestamp()` call, and got confused. The [`str()` conversion of a `datetime()` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__str__) formats the value as a [ISO 8601 string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat). Note that even if you **did** have a string, you used the wrong format (there is no timezone in that string, so `%Z` does not apply).

If you needed a `datetime` object, rather than a formatted string, you could also just have converted your timestamp to an integer; the microseconds are captured in the decimal portion of the timestamp:

```
>>> ctime = 1505252035.28109
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(ctime)
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 12, 22, 33, 55, 281090)
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ctime))
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 12, 22, 33, 55)
>>> print(_)
2017-09-12 22:33:55
```

Comment: Awesome. Now I have understood. Many thanks for the explanation and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time` as well to achieve what you want.

```
import time
ctime = "2017-09-12 22:33:55.28109"
x = time.strptime(ctime.split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
x = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', x)
print (x)
```

'09/12/2017 10:33:55 PM'